# Using elm-reactor with Elm embedded in HTML?

Tags: elm, elm-reactor

So I'm trying out Elm and WebRTC together. However for WebRTC I need some interop to javascript. So I created an index.html with the needed script includes, for both WebRTC and main.js.

However, I am using elm-reactor. Which is super nice. But there is no main.js. I can create it with elm-make, but then I would have to manually update it.

So, is there a way to have elm-reactor work together with embedded elm?

Note: I'm using Elm 0.18, latest as of writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to hack a bit, it's perfectly possible to [use your own index.html with elm reactor](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-reactor/issues/138#issuecomment-240940888). Just put the following in an index.html file and open it in reactor (e.g. http://localhost:8000/src/index.html):

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"><!-- Put your styles in folder with index.html -->
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center; color: #9A9A9A; font-family: &#39;Source Sans Pro&#39;;">
    <div style="font-size: 3em;">Building your project!</div>
    <img src="/_reactor/waiting.gif">
    <div style="font-size: 1em">With new projects, I need a bunch of extra time to download packages.</div>
  </div>
</body>

<!-- Fonts and external JS and styles are available, I've put Ace for example -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.4/ace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.4/theme-chrome.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.4/worker-lua.js"></script>

<!-- Put the name of your app here (my sources place in `src` forder) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_compile/src/YourApp.elm"></script>

<!-- Removes splash and starts elm app. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
while (document.body.firstChild) {
  document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
}
runElmProgram();
</script>

</html>
```

If you want to use ports or flags, use [the following example](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-reactor/issues/138#issuecomment-257984481) (you need `Elm.App.fullscreen(flags)` etc to use ports, but `runElmProgram()` to show errors):

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>a title</title>
<link href=/bundle.css rel=stylesheet>
<body></body>
<script src="/_compile/Main.elm"></script> <!-- this will fail in production -->
<script src="/elm-bundle.js"></script> <!-- this will fail in development -->
<script>
var app
var flags = {}

try {
  app = Elm.App.fullscreen(flags)

  /* app.ports is now available */
} catch (e) {
  // this will run in case there are compile errors:
  var stylesheets = document.querySelectorAll('link')
  for (var i = 0; i < stylesheets.length; i++) {
    stylesheets[i].parentNode.removeChild(stylesheets[i])
  }
  runElmProgram()
}
</script>
```

Comment: Has anyone had any luck exploring history using this method? I end up with my app's div sitting in front of the `<div>class="elm-overlay"</div>` making it impossible to interact with. Maybe this is worth asking as a separate question?

Comment: @Charlie Interesting, I just double checked one of my old projects and it works for me. My guess is that you have z-index issues. `.elm-overlay {z-index: 100;}` (or anything higher than what you use) should help.

Comment: Yes, that did it! Not sure why it was happening, but that's a great and simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at [elm-live](https://github.com/tomekwi/elm-live).

It has the same options that `elm-reactor` has, but you can use your own `index.html`.

Answer (score 4):

As of today(`0.18.0`), officially you can not use *elm-reactor* for embedding your application into custom HTML. It is also impossible to have port subscriptions with *elm-reactor* without additional setup.

Consider using something like [Create Elm App](https://github.com/halfzebra/create-elm-app#create-elm-app) or [alternatives.](https://github.com/halfzebra/create-elm-app#alternatives)